# Unit test in Python not running

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my code with unit tests, but when I try to run it it just says

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why isn't it working?

```
from Graph import Graph
import unittest

class GraphTest:

    def setUp(self):
        self.graph = Graph()
        for i in range(5):
            self.graph.addNode(i,"Node"+i)
        self.graph.addEdge(1,5,"Edge1,5")
        self.graph.addEdge(5,1,"Edge5,1")
        self.graph.addEdge(3,2,"Edge3,2")

    def test_Connected(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.graph.isConnected(1,5))
        self.assertTrue(self.graph.isConnected(5,1))
        self.assertTrue(self.graph.isConnected(3,2))
        self.assertFalse(self.graph.isConnected(2,3))
        self.assertFalse(self.graph.isConnected(1,4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make your `GraphTest` a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`